how to determine Threadpool size in Kubernetes
I want to create Threadpool
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads)

The POD resource configuration is as follows
     "limits": {
       "cpu": "800m",
       "memory": "1000Mi"
           },
    "requests": {
      "cpu": "23m",
      "memory": "288Mi"
   }
  

With this configuration, I am not sure how to correctly determine number of threads.
Somewhere I saw this equation
   Number of Threads = Number of Available CPU Cores * Target CPU Utilization * (1 +    Wait Time / Compute Time)

If this equation is valid then I did some calculation, lets say Target CPU Utilization is 80% and Wait Time / Compute Time for I/O intensive application is 10/1.
Number of Available CPU Cores = 800m from above configuration which I understood as 0.8 core
So the calculation becomes = 0.8 * 0.8 * (1 + 10/1)
Java version: 11
So Is this correct , if not then how can I determine number of threads?

thanks for your feedback, the answer you provided is the same link which I found before and I want to know what other's opinion on this.

I have checked multiple docs, there is only method as I mentioned in the solution.

To calculate or to determine the threadpool size in kubernetes the formula which you're using is correct and the formula is

Number of Threads = Number of Available CPU Cores * Target CPU Utilization * (1 +    Wait Time / Compute Time).

Before calculating we need to consider below two points :

Kubernetes uses millicore(or millicpu) resolution for CPU, 1000m equal to 1 CPU core then 800m it is 0.8 CPU Core. As per your calculation,  Number of Available CPU Cores = 800m from above configuration which I understood as 0.8 core.

If you have compute-intensive tasks so our (Wait Time / Compute Time) = 1/10. If you have IO heavy tasks and our (Wait Time / Compute Time) = 10/1


Based on above requirements,
If you have compute intensive task then
Number of Threads = 0.8* 0.8* (1 + 1/10) = 0.704

If you have IO heavy tasks then
Number of Threads = 0.8* 0.8* (1 + 10/1) = 7.04.

Refer to this Finding Ideal JVM Thread Pool Size With Kubernetes by Mucahit Kurt for more information.
